# Cannot publish content from site to Contentful -- ValidationFailed

Tags: javascript, c#, contentful

Contentful newbie here. I'm having an issue with publishing content from our team website to Contentful using Contentful's API (C# backend).

**Background:** We have a content type called **Post** with a `required` field called **Tags**. Whenever I try to publish content from our testing website to our Contentful space, I get the following error:

[image]

Here's the data I've been trying to pass. As you can see, `tags` is not empty:

```
"{"entry":{
    "fields":{
        "title":{"en-US":"test post 4"},
        "description":{"en-US":"test comment 4"},
        "tags":{"en-US":["Lobsters; test data","United States of America","China"]},
        "author":{"en-US":"admin"},
        "authorId":{"en-US":6},
        "yearStart":{"en-US":"2003"},
        "yearEnd":{"en-US":"2015"}
        }
    }
}"
```

I can't replicate this issue in my local environment. Tried contacting Contentful Support as well and they are as clueless about the cause as I am.

Any idea what could be causing this error?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by C# backend? Are you using the Contentful .NET SDK?

Comment: Hi Dee J! May I ask you to contact us at support@contentful.com and provide the ticket id you had with us earlier? Just want to figure out what happened and how can we help you with similar questions as fast as we can in future. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @AndreyTigay! Email sent. :)

Comment: Thank you @DeeJ! Just curious- were you able to send us an email to support@contentful.com? Asking because I don't see it...

Comment: @AndreyTigay Sorry for the late response. Yep, Gabriel from Contentful Support already replied. He said he'll be escalating it to your engineering team. For your reference, ticket # is 18525. :) Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: That's great! Sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

from the validation errors' detail field, it looks like you're using the `/spaces/:spaceId/assets` endpoint, not the `/entries` one, which is probably the one you want to use.

`url` is a special field for assets, which indicates where the actual file is located the Asset is referencing.

So make sure you're doing something like this:

```
curl \
-X PUT \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <accessToken>" \
-H "X-Contentful-Content-Type: post" \
-d '{"entry":{"fields":{"title":{"en-US":"test post 4"},"description":{"en-US":"test comment 4"},"tags":{"en-US":["Lobsters; test data","United States of America","China"]},"author":{"en-US":"admin"},"authorId":{"en-US":6},"yearStart":{"en-US":"2003"},"yearEnd":{"en-US":"2015"}}}}' \
https://api.contentful.com/spaces/<spaceId>/entries
```